# How to make this (scrollable div) work without jquery?

Tags: javascript

I've been making a webpage and I have one feature (making fixed divs scrollable) that requires some javascript, I've found a way to make it work with jquery but can't get it to work without it. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // A globar variable to save to last element that the following class was applied to
  var Last;
  // This adds the class "ttth" so that tt the class "tt" will be displayed.
  $(".tttw").live('touchstart', function() {
    if (Last) Last.removeClass('ttth');
    $(this).addClass("ttth");
    Last=$(this);
  });
  // Test if we have a touchdevice.
  function isTouchDevice(){
    try{
      document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
      return true;
    }catch(e){
      return false;
    }
  }
  // This function makes a fixed div on touch devices scrollable.
  function touchScroll(selector) {
    if (isTouchDevice()) {
      var scrollStartPosY=0;
      var scrollStartPosX=0;
      $('body').delegate(selector, 'touchstart', function(e) {
        scrollStartPosY=this.scrollTop+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
        scrollStartPosX=this.scrollLeft+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
      });
      $('body').delegate(selector, 'touchmove', function(e) {
        if ((this.scrollTop < this.scrollHeight-this.offsetHeight &&
          this.scrollTop+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY < scrollStartPosY-5) ||
          (this.scrollTop != 0 && this.scrollTop+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY > scrollStartPosY+5))
          e.preventDefault();
        if ((this.scrollLeft < this.scrollWidth-this.offsetWidth &&
          this.scrollLeft+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX < scrollStartPosX-5) ||
          (this.scrollLeft != 0 && this.scrollLeft+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX > scrollStartPosX+5))
          e.preventDefault();
        this.scrollTop=scrollStartPosY-e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
        this.scrollLeft=scrollStartPosX-e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
      });
    }
  }
  // Touch is being initialised.
  $(document).ready(function(){
    touchScroll('.tt');
  });
</script>
```

This code is already working but to reduce the loading time I want to get rid of jQuery. How to do that? For example - how can I select all classes "tttw" and add an eventlistener?

Any help, rough direction, etc. would be great!

Comment: I doubt that avoiding jQuery will make much of a difference in start-up time. You'd be better off moving your own code to a separate file so that it could be cached.

Comment: Have you actually measured the load times and confirmed slow loading is because of jQuery?

Comment: @Juhana: No - I have not measured that, but it will reduce the size that needs to be loaded.

Comment: @Pointy: Yes you are right. I will cache it as soon as I get rid of jQuery.

Comment: If you use a CDN as you do, most users already have it cached and don't need to download anything. Even if they do, the download time is most likely just fractions of a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - found the answer myself. I did it like this:

```
function touchScrolli(selector) {
    if (isTouchDevice()) { 
    var scrollStartPosY=0;
    var scrollStartPosX=0;
    var list = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    scrollStartPosY=this.scrollTop+e.touches[0].pageY;
    scrollStartPosX=this.scrollLeft+e.touches[0].pageX;
    e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
    list[i].addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    if ((this.scrollTop < this.scrollHeight-this.offsetHeight &&
    vthis.scrollTop+e.touches[0].pageY < scrollStartPosY-5) ||
    (this.scrollTop != 0 && this.scrollTop+e.touches[0].pageY > scrollStartPosY+5))
    e.preventDefault();
    if ((this.scrollLeft < this.scrollWidth-this.offsetWidth &&
    this.scrollLeft+e.touches[0].pageX < scrollStartPosX-5) ||
    (this.scrollLeft != 0 && this.scrollLeft+e.touches[0].pageX > scrollStartPosX+5))
    e.preventDefault();
    this.scrollTop=scrollStartPosY-e.touches[0].pageY;
    this.scrollLeft=scrollStartPosX-e.touches[0].pageX;
    });
    }
    }
}
```

Just needed to know how to select all classes without jQuery.